# Are licensed electricians required to perform code-compliant repairs?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, afci, contractors

A California licensed electrician replaced a circuit breaker for a friend. He removed the living room AFCI breaker and replaced it with a *used non-AFCI* breaker.

When I heard this I was upset enough that he installed a used breaker, but the CA Electric code requires an AFCI here (unless I am mistaken, I re-read the section).

Is it permitted to replace the breaker with a used one? Is it permitted to replace a compliant breaker with a non compliant breaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the AFCI was required in the first place, ie: the code in place when the circuit was originally installed (regardless if they are required now), then yes, removing it and replacing it with a standard breaker created a violation.

The rest is a legal issue and not appropriate for this forum. Have your friend call the building dept for the ONLY accurate answer.

Comment: +1. When it comes to code and what will pass inspection, always ask the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction. They're the ones you have to satisfy.